# Unable to login to firebase using cli

Tags: powershell, firebase, npm, firebase-tools

I'm currently following the [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/#4) for creating a web app with firebase, and I'm unable to login using `firebase login`. I've followed the steps up to that point. `firebase version` says it's `3.1.0`, so it has installed correctly. I'm running this through Powershell (same results when run through cmd) on Windows 10. I'm not sure if this is something related to firebase, or with npm (as I've never used it before). Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Here's the output when I try to login:

```
PS C:\Users\Tyler> firebase login --debug
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Command:      C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\bin\firebase login --debug
CLI Version:  3.1.0
Platform:     win32
Node Version: v7.1.0
Time:         Fri Nov 18 2016 18:05:11 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Error: write EINVAL
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at WriteStream.Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:715:26)
    at WriteStream.Socket._write (net.js:734:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:334:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:320:5)
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:247:11)
    at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:661:40)
    at MuteStream.ondata (stream.js:31:26)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at MuteStream.emit (events.js:188:7)

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
Error: This socket is closed
    at WriteStream.Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:683:19)
    at WriteStream.Socket._write (net.js:734:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:334:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:320:5)
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:247:11)
    at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:661:40)
    at Console.log (console.js:43:16)
    at module.exports.UI.onForceClose (C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\inquirer\lib\ui\baseUI.js:35:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at process.emit (events.js:188:7)

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
Error: This socket is closed
    at WriteStream.Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:683:19)
    at WriteStream.Socket._write (net.js:734:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:334:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:320:5)
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:247:11)
    at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:661:40)
    at Console.log (console.js:43:16)
    at process.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\bin\firebase:76:17)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at process.emit (events.js:188:7)

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

I've also tried using the --no-localhost option without success:

```
PS C:\Users\Tyler> firebase login --no-localhost --debug
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Command:      C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\bin\firebase login --no-localhost --debug
CLI Version:  3.1.0
Platform:     win32
Node Version: v7.1.0
Time:         Fri Nov 18 2016 18:08:04 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Error: write EINVAL
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at WriteStream.Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:715:26)
    at WriteStream.Socket._write (net.js:734:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:334:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:320:5)
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:247:11)
    at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:661:40)
    at MuteStream.ondata (stream.js:31:26)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at MuteStream.emit (events.js:188:7)

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
Error: This socket is closed
    at WriteStream.Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:683:19)
    at WriteStream.Socket._write (net.js:734:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:334:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:320:5)
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:247:11)
    at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:661:40)
    at Console.log (console.js:43:16)
    at process.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\bin\firebase:76:17)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at process.emit (events.js:188:7)

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
Error: This socket is closed
    at WriteStream.Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:683:19)
    at WriteStream.Socket._write (net.js:734:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:334:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:320:5)
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:247:11)
    at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:661:40)
    at Console.log (console.js:43:16)
    at module.exports.UI.onForceClose (C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\inquirer\lib\ui\baseUI.js:35:11)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:185:7)

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it looks like this was some ongoing issue with node/npm. Not entirely sure what this issue is, but I think it is related to the [following issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7919). Downgrading from node v7.1.0 to node v6.9.1 and installing firebase-tools again fixed the issue.